# Artifactory tomcat GhostCast Vulnerability

Tags: tomcat, artifactory, ajp

Just wondering does anyone know since the Artifactory RPM comes with Tomcat, will the Artifactory team be addressing the Tomcat Ghostcat Vulnerability anytime soon?

CVE-2020-1938 | Ghostcat - Apache Tomcat AJP File Read/Inclusion Vulnerability

Answer (score 2):

It appears this vulnerability affects only when tomcat is running with AJP connector. Artifactory does not use this protocol anymore.

UPDATE: If you are running Artifactory 7+ you are protected.

If your original installation of Artifactory was 6.10 and above you are protected.

To verify, check Artifactory's tomcat server.xml for AJP connector. If you do not have it, you are protected.
Look for connector with protocol="AJP/*"

For more information see: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Configuring+Apache

Comment: In the past Artifactory used to enable AJP. Please check Artifactory's tomcat server.xml. If you do not see the AJP connector, you are protected.